# I cant install,update I am using Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, updates, repository

sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Ign:4 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:5 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Ign:6 http://your.repo.domain/repository impish InRelease

The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:15 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports InRelease [65.9 kB]
Ign:6 http://your.repo.domain/repository impish InRelease

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: The repositories aren't there as the release went EOL.  Ubuntu 21.10 was the 2021-October release (ie. format is *year.month* with 2000 added to year) with 9 months of *supported* life; so adding 9 months to October would have told you EOL in July 2022 even if you didn't know which day it was released.  **After** a release goes EOL it's repositories are moved.. Please refer to the EOLUpgrades link in prior comment on fixing your issue (ie. removing the no *country* code & changing archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases).  Using a 2014-April (*trusty*) archive is *risky*, so I hope you're offline.